# multiple conditional statements in square brackets

Tags: r

Is there any way to put multiple conditional statements in the square brackets in R?

I tried something like

```
dataframe$column1 [dataframe$column2 == "value2" || dataframe$column3 == "value3"] <- "value 1"
```

to no avail.

I know I can just make two successive statements, but I was hoping for something more elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dataframe$column1[dataframe$column2 == "value2" | dataframe$column3 == "value3"] <- 
"value 1"
```

let me try to explain this with a reproducible example with our test dataframe:

```
dataframe <- data.frame(column1 = 1:3, column2 = 2:4, column3 = 3:5)

dataframe

      column1 column2 column3
1       1       2       3
2       2       3       4
3       3       4       5
```

if I have two statements separated by the logical OR operator in R `|` it gives me back an array of `length(dataframe)` with `TRUE` or `FALSE` if the statement matches a line:

```
dataframe$column2 == 2 | dataframe$column3 == 4
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

by calling this statement inside brackets we point to the correspondent row:

```
dataframe$column1[dataframe$column2 == 2 | dataframe$column3 == 4]
```

returns the values of column1:

```
[1] 1 2
```

we can now override these value:

```
dataframe$column1[dataframe$column2 == 2 | dataframe$column3 == 4] <- 4
```

finally

```
dataframe

      column1 column2 column3
1       4       2       3
2       4       3       4
3       3       4       5
```

Comment: Please, explain in more detail. The code alone isn't very helpful.